# Are there purely declarative, general purpose programming languages?

Tags: functional-programming, declarative, logic-programming

I've been researching declarative languages, and it seems like declarative is just an umbrella term for both logic and functional languages.  Or am I wrong?  Are there any general-purpose declarative programming languages that can't be classified as either functional or logic(al), and simply "declarative"?

Comment: Rules engines, SQL without stored procedures come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A declarative language requires you to code for **what** you want to happen rather than in an imperative language where you code **how** the computation should be done.

In general this means that a declarative language does not allow for side-effects, whereas imperative languages almost require coding with side-effects.

In order for general-purpose languages to be, well, general-purpose they require the ability to code side-effects. It thus make them hard to be declarative.

Languages like F# have a strong basis in functional programming, but have any constructs to allow for OO programming and side-effects. This makes F# a general purpose language but does so by allowing imperative style coding to be mixed in with declarative coding.

Although not entirely impossible, I would suspect that there are no "purely declarative" general purpose programming languages just simply by definition.

Comment: Are you unaware of functional programming languages that enforce purity (as opposed to F#, which allows arbitrary untracked side-effects anywhere), such as Haskell? Or do you think they don't count as purely declarative because they're capable of doing IO?

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question a bit. The question was whether there are declarative languages that aren't functional or logical.

Comment: @sepp2k - I think I answered the question in my last sentence in particular.

Comment: @Ben - I think it's a bit of a sliding scale. Without some degree to perform side-effects you can't do a lot of real-world work. But that same degree makes the language less declarative.

Comment: I've been looking into it and I realized that there is no general-purpose declarative language, so I saw an opportunity and I was hoping that I could figure out a way to make my own.  Then I asked this question.  Hmmm.

Comment: But there are languages that present pure declarative abstractions for how IO performed, such as Haskell and Mercury. If any (useful for actual programming) languages *at all* can be said to be declarative, then those can be said to be. Yet you mention F# instead. F# isn't even "really" declarative at all (the presence of untracked side-effects means you need an operational view to understand F# programs).

Comment: The thing that stops Haskell and Mercury being good answers to this question isn't that they can do IO and so aren't purely declarative, but rather that they are functional and logical respectively, and so aren't examples of declarative languages that are neither functional nor logical. You seem to be answering presupposing a definition of "declarative" that necessarily excludes all languages capable of being used for real work, which makes the question much less interesting than the one Matt asked.

Comment: @Ben, what would a declarative programming language that isn't logical or functional look like?  I'm trying to wrap my head around that...pseudo-code or something...
I'm having trouble understanding the difference between logic languages and functional languages and theoretical "pure" declarative languages...?
It seems to me that a "pure" declarative language is useless, perhaps, because you can only specify the problem, not what you want the computer to do with the problem...although what if the solution to a problem was to print out "hello world"?  That's a start, I think...maybe?

Comment: hey, guys, I found a really, really interesting paper on declarative languages: http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~mh/papers/ICLP07.pdf

Comment: @Matt the key to functional and logical programming languages is that each is based on a formal model, which has an effective algorithm for finding solutions. So then the programmer specifies the program in the model, and the language implementation is responsible for finding the solution. So if you could find a suitable formalism that wasn't much like the lambda calculus or predicate calculus, then you could perhaps call a language based on that formalism declarative but not functional or logical. I don't know of such a formalism, but I don't know why there shouldn't be any more.

Comment: Are predicate and lambda calculus the only systems found so far?

Comment: Technically, isn't lambda calculus a logic, so couldn't functional languages be described as logical languages too?  It'd be better if it was lambda languages and predicate languages...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16813/discussion-between-ben-and-matt)